# How can I record the steps in Microsoft Forms

Tags: forms

I have created a form with over 30 steps in Microsoft Forms with Branding.

Based on the user's selections within the form, the steps might be as few as 5 when they submit the form.

How can I know the number of steps and send a email to the admin?